# Django Queryset take too long to load

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I just uploaded a project to my server on digital ocean. When I load the Partnership view it takes about 1 minute before the data is queried and filtered an d then displayed. There are  1,905,120 entries to be filtered to display about 200,000 entries. How can I optimize the process?

views.py

```
class PartnershipView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView): 
model = Partnership
slug = ''
slug1 = ''
slug2 = ''

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
    slug1 = self.kwargs.get("slug1")
    slug2 = self.kwargs.get("slug2")

    currentYear = datetime.datetime.now().year
    currentMonth = calendar.month_name[datetime.datetime.now().month]
    partnershipArms = PartnershipArm.objects.all()

    context['partnershipArms'] = partnershipArms


    partnershipArm = PartnershipArm.objects.get(slug = slug)

    if slug =='':
        partnerships = self.get_queryset().filter(partnershipArm = partnershipArm, year=currentYear, month = currentMonth )
    else:
        partnerships = self.get_queryset().filter(partnershipArm = partnershipArm, year=slug1, month = slug2 )
    members = Member.objects.all()

    context['currentYear'] = currentYear
    context['currentMonth'] = currentMonth
    context['partnershipArmName'] = partnershipArm.name
    context['partnershipArm'] = slug
    context['partnerships'] = partnerships
    context['members'] = members
    context['year'] = slug1
    context['month'] = slug2

    return context
```

partnership_list.html

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>contact</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Week 1</th>
            <th>Week 2</th>
            <th>Week 3</th>
            <th>Week 4</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for instance in partnerships %}
        <tr>
        {% for member in members %}
        {% if member.pk == instance.member_id %}
            <td>{{ member.title }} {{ member.fname }} {{ member.lname }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.contact }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor%}
            <td><a href="{% url 'partnership-week1-update' partnershipArm instance.pk %}">{{instance.week1 }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'partnership-week2-update' partnershipArm instance.pk %}">{{ instance.week2 }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'partnership-week3-update' partnershipArm instance.pk %}">{{ instance.week3 }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'partnership-week4-update' partnershipArm instance.pk %}">{{ instance.week4 }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ instance.total }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

models.py

```
class PartnershipArm(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, null=True, blank=True)
partnershipRecords = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through = 'Partnership') 

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('partnership-arms')

class Partnership(models.Model):

YEAR = []
for r in range((datetime.datetime.now().year), (datetime.datetime.now().year+10)):
    YEAR.append((r,r))
MONTHS = (
    ('January', 'January'),
    ('February', 'February'),
    ('March', 'March'),
    ('April', 'April'),
    ('May', 'May'),
    ('June', 'June'),
    ('July', 'July'),
    ('August', 'August'),
    ('September', 'September'),
    ('October', 'October'),
    ('November', 'November'),
    ('December', 'December'),
)
member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
partnershipArm = models.ForeignKey(PartnershipArm, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
year = models.IntegerField( choices=YEAR, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
month = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = MONTHS, null=True, blank=True)
week1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
week2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
week3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
week4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
#keyChecker = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}".format(self.member, self.partnershipArm, self.year, self.month)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('partnership-arms')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted your models but you should make sure [to set a database index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques) (`db_index = True`) on each of these fields as you are using them in a `filter()`: `partnershipArm`, `year` and `month`.

Furthermore it is of course not the recommended way to display all the data on one page, you should rater use some sort of [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/) if your use case allows to do so.

In the template you are iterating through the members to find the right member for your partnership instance. If you have low number of members this might already be the faster way than using `select_related('member')` and accessing `instance.member` directly, but I would say this depends a lot on the number of members/partnerships in your database. If you still want to load the members in a seperate database query it would of course be the faster way to organize them in a dict with the id as the key so that you dont have to iterate over them for every row.

Comment: I have added my models now

Comment: Yes as I said you are lacking the indexes, using them should make the filtering faster in any case (make sure to run `makemigrations`/`migrate`).

Comment: sorry I'm a noob. I just read on db_index, should index all the fields ?

Comment: As I stated in my answer: Those you are filtering on!

Comment: select_related has improved speed